# Combinatorial formula for the number of different words

Tags: combinatorics

Does there exist a closed formula for the following:

Suppose we have $m$ distinct letters and we are allowed to use each letter at most $d$ times. What is the number of distinct words of length $k?$

In case such formula does not exist- can we effectively estimate this number from above and bellow?(in the sense of giving sharp asymptotic).
Indeed, one can find a recurrence formula for this sequence, but I do not quite how to effectively estimate it afterwards.

Comment: It seems like you could write down a recurrence relation on $k$, have you tried that approach?

Comment: If each word must have $k$ distinct letters I guess that the information that each letter can be used at most $d$ times is not important.

Comment: no the letters might repeat.

Comment: indeed one can write recession, but it is not clear how one can solve it...

Comment: The coefficient of x^k/k! in (1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/3! + x^4/4! + ... + x^d/d!)^m

Comment: right, the question is how one would estimate it afterwards? we can either proceed directly or try to maybe get our hands on the derivative of the corresponding expression and use cauchy integral formula. Both are not too clear to me at the moment